Seeking Versluys' "Trigonometric" Proof of the Pythagorean Theorem (#95 in his 1914 book)
I seek ("trigonometric") Proof #95 from Jan Versluys' 1914 book, Zes en negentig bewijzen voor het theorema van Pythagoras: verzameld en gerangschikt (translated from Dutch: Ninety-Six Proofs for the Pythagorean Theorem: collected and arranged), page 94.
I'm interested in the proof's original form and context, with whatever diagrams and/or commentary Versluys included.
My web searches have been fruitless, apart from the two references below and a preview-less Google Books entry.

Versluys #95 is mentioned in the 1940 edition of Elisha Loomis' The Pythagorean Proposition (PDF link via ed.gov):


Therefore the so-styled Trigonometric Proof, given by J. Versluys, in his Book, Zes en Negentig Bewijzen, 1914 (a collection of 96 proofs), p. 94, proof 95, is not a proof since it employs the formula $\sin^2A+\cos^2 A=1$.


Versluys #95 is described in Jason Zimba's 2016 note "On the Possibility of Trigonometric Proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem" (via academia.edu) (footnote 4):


A similar maneuver [to trying to derive $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ by substituting $\alpha=\beta=x$ and $\cos 0=1$ in [the identity $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta$] was attempted in 1914 by J. Versluys, who took $\alpha+\beta=\pi/2$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ in [the identity $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$]. Versluys cited Schur as the source of this idea (see [[Verluys' 1914 book], p.94]). A sign of trouble with the approach of Versluys/Schur is that the diagram typically used to derive the addition formula cannot
be drawn for the case $\alpha+\beta=\pi/2$.


An online copy is available from the University of Amsterdam. You can find p. 94ff here.
It's just one page without illustration so I'll reproduce it here:

The mentioned reference of Schur in full is:

Schur, Friedrich (1898). Lehrbuch der analytischen Geometrie. Veit.

The argument can be found in pages 19-21. On page 21 it is claimed to be a proof of the Pythagorean theorem, see excerpt:


Is "the diagram typically used to derive the addition formula" that "cannot be drawn for the case $\alpha+\beta=\pi/2$" what Schur has on p. 20 as Fig. 18?

@Conifold That's my best guess. If true, Zimba claims that the diagram fails for $\alpha+\beta=\pi/2$ but this seems to misunderstand Schur's argument where he - in paragraph leading up to (8) - states how he fixes them ($\beta=\alpha+\pi/2$). To me, Schur essentially derives consequences of projections between two rotated rectilinear coordinate systems. Addition formula and the square formula pop out. I.e. I don't follow Zimba's concern here. Also note: Loomis claims that the use of (13) is circular in Versluys. But note that it's derived and not assumed in Schur.
